# How to inject the Presenter class which has an interface as its constructor parameter in the Activity class using dagger 2?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I need to inject the Presenter class inside the activity using Dagger2 but to instantiate the Presenter class, I need to pass an interface as a parameter from Activity.

Without using dagger2 :

```
 Interface interface;
 interface = this;
 Presenter presenter = new Presenter(interface);
```

How to achieve this using Dagger2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide Activity in your @Provides method. How to make your activity actually available there depends on how you implemented DI with Dagger.

If you use @ContributesAndroidInjector, then you have automatic access to your activity in your @Module and you can just name it in your @Provides method arguments. Remember tou use your exact Activity class.

Provide presenter like this:

```
@Provides
Presenter providePresenter(YourActivityName activity) {
    return new Presenter((Interface) activity);
}
```